# How to permanently remove file crunching error in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I update my android studio to latest version 2.2.2 and Gradle version 1.4.1

But from the version 2.2 when I upgrade my all project to this one.

I always get this error in new version of Android studio, but all projects was working perfectly in previous version of android studio.

> Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>   Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

How can I disable or remove this check permanently ?

Comment: these are caused by some bad png files in your project. You have to identify it and remove it from your project

Comment: project was working fine in previous android studio version and also sometime it is working in current android studio version 2.2.2.
I want to disable crunching check in my all project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try adding this to `build.gradle` file

```
android{

    aaptOptions {  
        cruncherEnabled = false  
    } 
}
```

Note : it's not really a good idea to disable it because you will end up in increasing the apk size (in most cases) because you are disabling the image size optimization by doing this though i still recommend to open bad images in some image editor and use  `save as` with `.png` format

Comment: Well you are right, but in some situation I need to disable cruncher.

Comment: @Jayesh in case if there are lot of images and you wanna find out the problematic image then you can try the command in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36495978/some-file-crunching-failed-see-logs-for-details/36498031) here , hopefully help