# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. > Error: Some file crunching failed,. see logs for details . i ALways have this Error

Tags: android

HELO ANY SUGGESTION WOULD BE HELPFUL.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> Error: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

Error:Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

WHENEVER I RUN MY ANDROID APP IT SHOWS THE FOLLOWING MESSAGE. I HAVE ALSO RESTARTED MY PC AND ANDROID STUDIO SOFTWARE AND ALSO CREATED A NEW PROJECT. BUT STILL HAVING THIS PROBLEM.

Comment: please add your whole log cat

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36495978/some-file-crunching-failed-see-logs-for-details' .My guess is there is a corrupt image file in res. Check if you are able to open every image.

Comment: Please do not use caps

Answer (score 1):

Try this. This may help you

```
android {
    aaptOptions {  
                cruncherEnabled = false  
            } 
        }
```

One more thing, Make sure to clear cache and rebuild project.