# "Error:Some file crunching failed, see logs for details" when added google services

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

There is an issue when building a project with google services included. I added the following google services classpath to the root `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
}
```

and the project starts to complain with the following error when compiled:

> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> Error: Some file crunching failed, see logs for details

I checked the logs for the IDE, but there seems to be no issue there. How do I fix this so that I could include google services in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36495978/some-file-crunching-failed-see-logs-for-details), same error was encountered.

If you have **.9.png** files, try to remove them and test. In this post the user has many 9 patch images which is a possible reason of crunching problem.

Another thing is to add the code below to your **`build.gradle`** file.

```
 android {
    aaptOptions {  
       cruncherEnabled = false  
    } 
 }
```

By doing this, you will be able to exposed the incorrect references and files with issues that needed some fix. Before rebuild, don't forget to clear cache.

Comment: Thanks for the info. It was really an issue about image files. Is it because the images were too big, which led the IDE failed to compile?